# Differentiating sums with Maxima

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

I have the following sum:

```
sum((R[i]-(a*X[i]+b)*t + 1/2*(c*X[i]+d)^2*t)^2/((c*X[i]+d)^2*t), i, 1, N);
```

which I want to differenciate wrt. a:

```
diff(%, a);
```

but Maxima (wxMaxima to be precise) just prints d/da . Can I
make it actually differentiate the sum (so because N is finite is
should differentiate every element in the sum separately)?

If I set N to some constant, e.g.:

```
sum((R[i]-(a*X[i]+b)*t + 1/2*(c*X[i]+d)^2*t)^2/((c*X[i]+d)^2*t), i, 1, 100);
```

then I get explicit sum of 100 elements (takes about 2 pages), and
then differentiation works (but again I get 2 pages instead of a small
sum). Can I get this result displayed as a sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) do you use ?

Here is my session of Maxima with you equation differentiated wrt.a and than substituted to `N=100`.

```
~$ maxima 
Maxima 5.24.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp SBCL 1.0.51
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) sum((R[i]-(a*X[i]+b)*t + 1/2*(c*X[i]+d)^2*t)^2/((c*X[i]+d)^2*t), i, 1, N);
                                   2
                         (c X  + d)  t
                   N         i                             2
                  ====  (------------- - (a X  + b) t + R )
                  \            2             i           i
                   >    ------------------------------------
                  /                           2                                                                                                
                  ====              (c X  + d)                                                                                                 
                  i = 1                 i                                                                                                      
(%o1)             ------------------------------------------                                                                                   
                                      t                                                                                                        
(%i2) diff(%, a);                                                                                                                              
                                       2                                                                                                       
                             (c X  + d)  t                                                                                                     
                    N            i
                   ====  X  (------------- - (a X  + b) t + R )
                   \      i        2             i           i
(%o2)          - 2  >    --------------------------------------
                   /                            2
                   ====               (c X  + d)
                   i = 1                  i
(%i3) %, N=100;
                                       2
                             (c X  + d)  t
                   100           i
                   ====  X  (------------- - (a X  + b) t + R )
                   \      i        2             i           i
(%o3)          - 2  >    --------------------------------------
                   /                            2
                   ====               (c X  + d)
                   i = 1                  i
```

Comment: I am using wxMaxima 11.08.0 (Maxima version: 5.24.0) from Debian.

Comment: It seems like the same Maxima version. Do you have same output as me? I hope my output helped.

Comment: I actually managed to get the differentiation working by setting simplify_sum:true. I am wondering what are other default options that are counterintuitive for newbies.

Comment: All depends on application. Most probably you might like to check [Manual Category: Simplification functions](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_100.html#Category_003a-Simplification-functions). I've found usefull [Manual Category: Evaluation flags](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_100.html#Category_003a-Evaluation-flags) especially [nouns](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_8.html#Item_003a-nouns) useful (of course in combination with `ratsimp`, `float()` etc).